# Do all the scripts that are run in "rc.local" display results on the terminal or do they just run in the background?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, boot

Do all the scripts that are run in *rc.local* display results on the terminal or do they just run in the background?

What if I want the scripts to run before the startup and wait for the user input to continue?
Is it possible? (I'm running these scripts on remote server)

Answer (score 1):

The scripts are not associated with a terminal so they do not display their results there (which does not necessarily mean they run in the background)

The solution will vary a bit depending on your setup.  I have not tried it, but on Fedora or similar you may want to try making your script as an "init" script and dumping it in /etc/rc.d/init.d [depending on your OS]